# How do I input a series of numbers (separated by comma) using system argument in command prompt (Python)?

Tags: python, pycharm, command-prompt

I just started learning Python. I want to input a series of numbers that are separated by a comma in command prompt.

For example, I want to input this in the command prompt:
C:\AOA1001\Folder1\Testing> python Testing.py **1,2,3,4,5**

I get this error in command prompt:

```
C:\Users\belle\Folder1\Testing> Testing.py 1,2,3,4,5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\belle\Folder1\Testing> Testing.py", line 4, in <module>
    n = int(sys.argv[1])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,2,3,4,5'
```

This is my code:

```
import sys

try:
    n = int(sys.argv[1])
    print(n)

except IndexError:
    print("Invalid input.")
```

I am planning to create a list which is (n = int(sys.agrv[1]) in this case.

Comment: What do you want to do with these values? Build a list? This can't be an int anyway if you have more than one value. You should clarify your question;

Comment: yes. i want to calculate the summation of even numbers in an input list (which is n = int(sys.argv[1]) in this case). i want the user to input a series of numbers separated by commas in one line (e.g " testing.py 1,2,3,4,5")

Comment: OK, you should edit your question to make your requirements clear.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille will do. i'm sorry for the unclear question.

Answer (score 0):

```
str_numbers = sys.argv[1].split(',')
numbers = list(map(lambda x: int(x), str_numbers))
print(numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put them in a list:

```py
import sys

try:
    lst = [int(s) for s in sys.argv[1].split(',')]
    print(lst)

except ValueError:
    print("Invalid input.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it into a list:

```
import sys

try:
    n = map(int, sys.argv[1].split(','))
    print(*list(n))
except IndexError:
    print('Invalid Input')
```

And, then in the command line:

```
python3 .\Testing.py 1,2,3,4,5
>>> 1 2 3 4 5
```